# How to get back the files removed with `git rm -r -f`?

Tags: git

I did

```
git rm -f -r
```

thinking all the files *from the index* will be removed but they have been removed from my folder.

How do I get my files back?

Answer (score 1):

If your working directory still exists and it contains a `.git` subdirectory then you can use `git reset --hard HEAD` and it will re-create the working directory from the current git commit indicated by HEAD.

Your problem looks like in adding the upstream you have added an extra argument. You need:

```
git remote set-url origin https://...
```

or

```
git remote add origin https://....
```

Answer (score 0):

If your files have already been pushed, a fast fix would be the clone the repository again from github.

Otherwise, if your files have been tracked by git, your should be able to recover them using the git reflog command.

Otherwise, consider using some file recovery software (i.e http://pcsupport.about.com/od/filerecovery/tp/free-file-recovery-programs.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the status of your repository after the removal:

1. If `git status` does not show any changes you want to preserve, then you can simply revert the repository back to the last commit: `git reset --hard HEAD` or `git reset --hard` (the commit that HEAD points to is the default argument)
2. If there are changes that you want to preserve that you've already added to the index with `git add`, then both these changes and the removal of files will be in the index. In this case, you'll have to separate these changes manually. For example, you can do `git reset --soft -- <path_to_file>` on the files that **contain changes you want to keep**. Then you stash non-staged files with `git stash --keep-index`. Then you revert the repository to the last commit with `git reset --hard`. And finally you reapply the changes you stashed beforehand with `git stash apply`. Check to see that everything is cool and drop the stashed information with `git stash drop`.
3. If there are changes you want to keep which haven't been added to the index yet, then use method #2 and just ommit the first stage (soft reset of changes you want to keep).

Please note that if there were any modifications in the removed files prior to removal, then you will not be able to restore them with Git.

Off-topic: I didn't quite understand what was your initial intent, but maybe `git rm --cached` is the command you are looking for.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Hi i got the answer and retrieved the files 
so i did

git status

which showed the  changes to be committed
then to unstage the commit i executed

git reset HEAD

you have to execute above command with filename

so the above command unstaged all the changes then

git status

which showed changes not staged for commit

git checkout --

you have to execute above command with file name

so i got back all of my files

for further explanation you can see 
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/accidantally-deleted-project-with-git-rm-how-to-get-it-back-773539/